# Next DAG run stuck in "running" if previous run failed

Tags: airflow

is it normal in Airflow that if a DAG run fails, then the next scheduled DAG run gets stuck in the "running" state with all of its tasks in the "no status" state?

This happens consistently for us, so presumably it is expected behaviour according to whichever arguments we have set that define that behaviour, but I don't know which arguments

Interested to know if we can get the next run to complete anyway in the event that the previous failure was a temporary issue

Answer (score 0):

No, typically after failing run dag run should succeed if there are no any errors in the previous dag run you should potentially fix.

I recommend you revisit the Scheduler logs to see why it's hanging.

Comment: sorry for not replying or accepting a solution. I am waiting for this issue to happen again. Usually it is quite common, but it has been a while

Comment: sorry, I'm quiting my job and won't be testing this. Thanks for the answer, but I wont be a position to accept it

Answer (score 0):

There is a great write up about what can happen over at https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/airflow_tasks_stuck_in_no_status/ that explains why subsequent DAG runs will fail in this state due to errors from the first run and how to solve it. Even if the DAGs look identical there can be changes made during runs that don't line up that will result in this exact error.